# why does it take so long for some specific number when doing iteration

Tags: python, algorithm

there
I was solving a problem today, I use the iterative way of solving the problem , and here is my code, I'm so confused why some numbers like below take seemly infinite time to run ,while others(roughly same magnitude )(123456789,787654321) take less than a second to run, I just con't figure out where i did wrong, can anyone help?

```
y,x =123456789,987654321
def ksi(x,y):
    z=1
    result=0
    while x>0:
        if x>=y:
            x=x-y
            result =result+z
        else:
            y=y-x
        z = 2*z
    return result
```

Comment: Those are not of the same magnitude. The code snippet is 10x the `12345678` value.

Comment: oh, sorry, even if i change it to (123456789, 787654321) it still took  only 0.008978128433227539 second to run

Comment: Try `print(x, y)` inside the loop and you'll understand. Basically `x` becomes a really small value while `y` remains a really big value, so the loop spends millions of iterations subtracting `x` from `y`.

Comment: thanks @Rawing, i can see when x =9, y =123456789, it took long time to iterate.

Comment: What are you trying to solve?  Seems to be me that this can be easily solved only by using the quotient and reminder of the numbers instead of going through these subtraction loops.  For x = 100, and y = 19, the if x>= y loop will execute for 5 times (which is int(100/19)) then x becomes 5 and y is 19, the else loop will be executed 3 times (int(19/5)), then y will be 4 and x will be 5.  etc.  But everytime you are multiplying z by 2 but adding z to the result only when x >=y.

Comment: hi@narasimman,you are right, I was dealing with a math equation , however the result is roughly the size 2** 109739369, when i calculate that , i encountered overflow, any idea to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You have an exponential time algorithm, though sometimes you get lucky and the algorithm solves quickly.

To see the worst case, put in `y=1`.  What happens?  You decrement `x` by 1 every iteration.  So if `x` is 1,000,000,000,000, then this is going to run 1,000,000,000,000 iterations.  That's a long, long time.

Why is that exponential?  When we measure complexity, we talk about the running time as a function of the input **size**.  When `y=1` (a special case for input), its running time is `O(x)`, but `x` is size `n = log2 x` bits (and hence `n = 2^x`).  A polynomial time algorithm would need to be `O(n^k)` for some integer `k`.  But what you have in this case is running time `O(2^n)`, which makes the exponential time more clear.

Side remark: it is worse than exponential thanks to `z` but let's not go down that direction now.

What you are implementing here reminds me of a gcd computation.  Instead of subtracting a single value each time, instead subtract as much as you can per iteration.  As much as you can is calculated by division and remainder.  Once you do that, you will have a polynomial time algorithm.  Read up on gcd computations in Knuth's Semi-numerical algorithms (Art of computer programming volume 2) -- this whole subject is fascinating.

Comment: thanks @TheGreatContini, I'll look at that book, have no previous experience in algorithm. For the above problem ,let's say x =1, y =1,000,000 ,z =1 ,every time y decrease 1, z *=2 ,the result should be 2**1,000,000 when y =1 right? So for large exponentials like this one ,is there any way to get the result faster?

Comment: @riversxiao That is correct (`z`), but I don't think you have the right algorithm here.  I think you have an erroneous algorithm that is attempting to [compute the gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).  Please read up about Euclidean algorithm before you try to optimise too much, because the value of `z` the way it is computed here just cannot be what you really want.